# Как экспортировать javaFX проект в jar файл

Tags: kotlin, javafx, intellij-idea

Я написал программу на kotlin с использованием javaFX в IntelliJ IDEA.
При запуске программы через IDEA все работает, но когда пытаюсь создать артефакт

То при создании javaFX application выдает ошибку can't build artifact fx:deploy is not available in this jdk

А при создании JAR файла он создается, но при попытке запустить в командной строке выдает javafx runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

При настройки создания артефакта я добавлял в сборку javaFX библиотеки. Я перепробовал ве варианты что нашел на просторах интернета, но ничего не помогло пока что

Comment: Многое зависит от версии JDK где собираете и где будете запускать. Вот тут все хорошо расписано. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html

Comment: У меня версия JDK 17, знаю что артифакт спокойно создается для JDK 8, но в inteeliJ IDEA нельзя даже создать JavaFX проект с использованием JDK 8, пишет, что необходима минимум 11 версия

Comment: В JDK 8 был включен FX, поэтому там проблем нет. Потом он ушел в свободное плавание, и теперь это уже другой FX, которому нужен JDK 11.
https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-java

Comment: Это я понимаю, но это понимание не решает проблемы, как создать артифакт на последних версиях. Должен же быть способ, иначе какой смысл в создании приложения, если не можешь распространить его.

Comment: Тут скорее не как создать артефакт, с этим проблемы минимальные. Как создать среду исполнения, вот что сложнее. FX требует платформозависимые модули для JVM. По последней ссылке, что я привел, вся информация есть (раздел Runtime images). Делал как-то один раз, получилось. И у вас получится.

Comment: Делаю по инструкции, но после команды 
javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX_MODS% -d mods/hellofx @sources.txt
ничего не происходи, хотя делаю все так же, переменные установлены, sources.txt создан.